# Filtering through an array of nested objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sanity

I'm having a bit of trouble. This is the data that I'm receiving back from my headless CMS (Sanity) and I want to be able to create a filter that matches the selected category.
I know that if my response was a category object that I could easily do the filter like so. However, I have some blogs that fall into several categories. I'm assuming that I would need to map through the category array and apply the filter here. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

```
  const router = useRouter();
  const { category: activeCategory } = router.query;
  const filteredBlogs = React.useMemo(() => {
    return activeCategory
      ? blogs.filter(
          (blog) => blog.category?.slug?.current === activeCategory
        )
      : downloads;
  }, [activeCategory, blogs]);
```

```
{
        "mainImage": {
          "asset": {
            "url": "https://cdn.sanity.io/images/s4nay89j/production/186a158c78e3d37ebe43c4197fe5f8c7854d0ae1-750x500.webp"
          }
        },
        "image": null,
        "title": "Keeping A Fitness Journal to Find Your Perfect Routine",
        "slug": {
          "current": "keeping-a-fitness-journal-to-find-your-perfect-routine"
        },
        "date": "2022-06-12",
        "category": [
          {
            "name": "Fitness",
            "slug": {
              "current": "fitness"
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "Motivation",
            "slug": {
              "current": "motivation"
            }
          }
        ]
      },
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `some()` function returns true if at least one of the array items match the condition. Your blog filter will be something like this:

```js
blogs.filter((blog) =>
  blog.category?.some((category) => category?.slug?.current === activeCategory)
)
```

Comment: `(blog) => (blog.category?.map(cat => cat?.slug?.current) || []).includes(activeCategory)` would also work, but I believe `.some` is more performant, as it exits after first match.